# uname reports different version in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I'm trying to verify the Ubuntu version on a tablet running 18.04 LTS but `uname` is reporting a different patch number than other methods:

```
$ uname -v
#46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020

$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

$ hostnamectl | grep Ubuntu
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

$ grep 'VERSION=' /etc/os-release
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

Comment: Your system is outdated; a fully upgraded *bionic* system will report itself as 18.04.5 so you're at least a year behind on upgrades and security fixes. The .1 in the `uname` result is expected and doesn't relate to the *upgrade* level of your system (but you ARE unpatched for many flaws so update asap!)  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the 18.04.5 ISO release date, but installed systems upgrade to it before that date

Comment: Thank you!  Can you point to documentation regarding the `uname` behavior in Ubuntu and add it as an answer @guiver